# Strange mysql_ multiple connections issue

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I'm kinda going crazy about this problem. I can't do it myself so I need the community to help me get this thing solved. I've been spending hours on this because I didn't know where to look. I now know a possible fix but it's just messy (read on). I just need someone who knows more about this than I do.

This is my situation:

- I want to use 2 or more mysql connections.
- I use OOP

I have a class called dbase, it has two functions, `setConnection` and `getConnection` and two class variables called `$connection` and `$dbaseName`.

In my main project file I include dbase and create two objects:

- dbase
- maindbase

then I do:

```
$this->dbase->setConnection($server, $uname, $pword);
$this->maindbase->setConnection($server, $uname, $pword);
```

the setConnection function looks like this:

```
function setConnection ($server, $serv_Username, $serv_Password) {
    $this->connection = mysql_connect($server, $serv_Username, $serv_Password, true);
    // echo $this->connection . "<BR>";
}
```

I echo it to see the `resourcenumber` and added **true** to mysql_connect (and I know it's deprecated since 5.5, I'm not here for that).

Now, as I understand OOP, the class variables are set per object. So $connection from dbase will never be the same as `maindbase` (unless, of course, I use the same credentials, but even then it will create a new link because of the $new_link option I enabled). They both have different resource ID's.

My problem:

In class dbase I also have a function which runs a query like this:

```
$connection = $this->getConnection();
$dbase_name = $this->getDbaseName();
mysql_select_db($dbase_name, $connection); 
$q = "SELECT * FROM {$table_name} WHERE {$column} LIKE '{$value}'";
$result = mysql_query($q);
```

Now, when I use it like this, it will ALWAYS use the FIRST $connection that has been set in class dbase and it doesn't matter which object this is, either object dbase or `maindbase`.

I get this error:

```
Table 'testdbase1.skye_domains' doesn't exist
```

object dbase is connected to testdbase1

object `maindbase` is connected to testdbase2

the above error I get when trying to select results using the `maindbase` object.

When I remove the `$connection` string from `mysql_select_db` it works perfectly because it will try to open a new connection as if using mysql_connect.

Why is this? This is impossible right? How can object`maindbase` have the same $connection as object dbase? They are in NO WAY connected to eachother... Is PHP somehow using a global mysql_connect variable or buffer which I'm not aware about?

I would like to keep using `connectionstrings` as this is just handy now and then. Leaving the $connection string out seems messy.

Does anybody have any suggestions I can try to make PHP (or my head) sane again?

Comment: Why on earth are you still using `mysql_` functions?

Comment: @DC_ "and I know it's deprecated since 5.5, I'm not here for that" already mentioned

Comment: @swapnesh Doesn't mean I can't ask.

Comment: @DC_ you can ask ... just sounds too loud in this case :)

Comment: @ DC_ keywords: using php 5.3, not enough time to rewrite the entire dbase class (it's big) (also, I'm from that time when dinosaurs roamed the earth), mysql_ works just fine. Can you help me fix this? and swapnesh, any idea?

Comment: @C-TZ why $this->dbase->setConnection($server, $uname, $pword); ?  i think dbase is an object then you can use method like this -- $dbase->setConnection($server, $uname, $pword);

Comment: swapnesh, I use $this because I run it from __construct in another class with functions which also use the same dbase and maindbase objects. If it has anything to do with this, what could it be?

Basically it's like this... I include a class which has a __construct and other functions who use dbase and maindbase objects. I include the dbase class in __construct.

Comment: I could also use $this->dbase::setConnection(blabla) but this is not the issue..

Comment: @ swapnesh, see this post to see why I use $this-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978478/php-and-mysql-connections?rq=1

Comment: Why on earth don't you just use [`mysqli`](http://hk1.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) for OOP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put echo $this->connection EVERYWHERE you use it. Also, create an "id" member and fill it with a unique value upon constructing a dbase-object and echo it along the value of $this->connection. This way you can track where what happens to your connection.

And check if there's maybe some place *outside* of the class that assigns $foo->connection. If you're not using "private" on the members, you're bound to have such problems when you e.g. forget to remove a hack or an experiment from unrelated parts of your code.

Comment: The $dbase_name string somewhat functions like an id. I echo it and it's ok. (dbase has testdbase1 as $dbase_name and maindbase has testdbase2 as $dbase_name).

There are only TWO points in the entire project where setConnection is used and that is in __construct of the main project class which then includes dbase class.

I've just doublechecked and I also have a sessionmanager which uses mysql_connect but it has NO RELATION WHATSOEVER to the dbase and maindbase objects!

Even when I set the two class variables to private the same problem ocures. It's really strange.

Comment: also I use $this->connection at the top of each function through getConnection where I pass it to a local variable (local as in, function scope -like). So this is SUPER safe in relation to things that could mess with the connectionstring.

Comment: I know whats wrong! You use mysql_query($q), but you MUST MUST MUST use mysql_query($q,$this->connection);!

Comment: Aaaaaaaah GOD!!!!!!! You're a lifesaver... I totaly missed that. I automaticaly assumed that when using mysql_select_db the right parameters were passed to mysql_query... I feel like such a moron right now. How could I have overlooked such a simple thing?? Maybe it's because I get 5 hours of sleep, barely, every night :'). I rechecked the manual on said function and you're right. It does need a link identifier to function properly.

Dude (or dudette), I love you. You saved my day, I can get some sleep now.

Comment: Hehe, happened too often for me :D That's why everyone recommends the mysqli_* functions, they don't allow that kind of mistake by forcing you to use a link id - aside from the other benefits. If possible, migrate your library to mysqli, after getting a nice sleep ;)